edmx-file support in new Windows 11 and VS install
I've just installed a fresh Windows 11 with VS 2022, and now I can't open edmx-files in non-core projects.
How can I add support for edmx-files again, so I can update the model from the database?
Or is there a way to update the model using a command? The solution and projects run on Framework 4.7.2.
I'm trying to open edmx-files.

Did you install the EF 6 Tools

I've installed your extension EF Core Power Tools, but it isn't working.
I can see it requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6, but I can't install a later version than 3.1.32. If I try updating to 6.0, it gives me the error:
Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.31'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

EF Core Power Tools is not the EF 6 tools, EF 6 tools is a Visual Studio component

Yes, Entity Framework 6 Tools is installed in Visual Studio 2022

VS repair could work??

I've solved opening and editing edmx-files! Uninstall Visual Studio 2022. Use this following page to find the first version of VS 2022: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history - When it is installed first upgrade to LTSC 17.8 and after that to the latest version. I tried to upgrade directly from 17.0 to LTSC 17.10, but VS 2022 crashed when trying to open the solution.

So "repair" The hard way??

Repair didn't have any effect. The ability to open edmx-files has been removed in newer versions of VS 2022, so by installing the oldest VS 2022 and upgrade will keep the ability.

Nevermind, it wasn't a workable solution. If you install a version older than 17.4, it doesn't run optimal on a MacBook (using Parallels) with arms processor. And from 17.4 edmx files is no longer supported. What a paradox! I'm back to zero updating my ef model from the database.

I've come up with a weird solution to work on old solutions with edmx-files. Install VS 19 alongside 2022. In VS 19 you can open edmx-files and update the model.

You are probably making itvery hard for yourself by running ARM VS
